# Are there alternatives to validate the domain for mailgun?

Tags: dns, verification, mailgun

We want to use the mailgun api (in a parse project) and tried to verify our domain.

We are supposed to change the DNS-Record of

**mailo. _domainkey.**

But our hoster (strato) tells us that this is not possible at all. It's one of the biggest hoster in Germany!

Is there another way to verify our domain? We just want to send emails and don't want to receive them through mailgun.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider switching registrars (or at least DNS providers). This is called a "TXT" record, and it is considered a standard feature of DNS.